# JavaScript / Jquery HTML Export DOM Structure/Page to HTML File or Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to modify through the dom various element properties and then save that page as an html file. View source doesn't always reflect dom adjustments. Is there a way to write the whole page to a file or otherwise get the updated source page into a file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm thinking this should do the trick for ya.

```
$('html').html();
```

JavaScript can't write files when being ran from a browser (security).    But you can send this to a PHP script and write it to a file from there.  For example:

```
$.post('write.php', { dom : $('html').html() });
```

**write.php**

```
file_put_contents('new.html', urldecode($_POST['dom']));
```

Answer (score 7):

In [newish browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=bloburls) (IE 10, FF 20, Chrome 26, Safari 6, Opera 15), you can create a `Blob` and save it into a file using `window.URL.createObjectURL`.

[Demo](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html), [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.URL.createObjectURL):

```
objectURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

- Where `blob` is a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/File) object or a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Blob) object to create a URL object for.
- `objectURL` is the generated object URL. The entire contents of the specified file are represented by the text of the URL. It can then be used in `window.open`.

Example of a `Blob`:

```
var parts = ["<p class=\"paragraph\"><a id=\"link\">hey!<\/a><\/p>"];
new Blob(parts, { "type" : "text\/html" });
```

To list current Blobs in Chrome execute the following in your address bar:

```
chrome://blob-internals
```

Comment: Support for this is pretty good in other browsers too now, definitely works in my Firefox version [http://caniuse.com/#feat=bloburls](http://caniuse.com/#feat=bloburls) eg: window.open(window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([document.documentElement.outerHTML], {type: 'text/plain'})));

Comment: Hello Radek, if I already have a file with the same name in my downloads folder is there a way to overwrite its contents and not create another file?

Comment: @Kumar this is unrelated to the question. Browsers will create a new version of the file by changing the filename a bit to make it unique. If you'd like to overwrite the original content, look at say writing a little Node.js script that request a file and stores it locally; e.g. https://github.com/request/request#streaming