# How do you match all quotes NOT contained with HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

In the following string...

```
var str = 'Foobar is so "awesome."  I <span prop="nifty">"really"</span> <span prop="attr">think it is so</span> <span prop="nifty" prop="attr">"cool!"</span>'
```

...how would I write a regular expression that matches the quotes (") around the words awesome, really, and cool, while NOT matching the quotes within the HTML tags?

I'm using JavaScript's replace function to replace the quotes with `&#34;`

I'm hoping there's a regular expression that I can use such that...

```
str.replace(/regex-magic/g, "&#34;")
```

..gives me the output...

```
Foobar is so `&#34;`awesome.`&#34;`  I <span prop="nifty">`&#34;`really`&#34;`</span> <span prop="attr">think it is so</span> <span prop="nifty" prop="attr">`&#34;`cool!`&#34;`</span>
```

Thanks much!!

Comment: @Barmar it'd be really cool to know the RegEx for how to do this.

Comment: If your HTML is generated by some backend then you should have it html escape all content strings automatically. Markup should not be part of your content...

Comment: That's invalid HTML.

Comment: @philtune Questions like this come up all the time. The almost universal answer is not to try to do it with regexp.

Comment: Required link to the canonical answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/938516

Comment: Why would you want to? `"` and `&#34;` in a text node mean exactly the same thing (except that `&#34;` is significantly less efficient)

Comment: @Barmar gotcha... I had always had this question in the back of my mind but never searched it. Interrobang's link explains this quite sufficiently. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = str.replace(/"(?![^<>]*>)/g, "&#34;");
```

`(?![^<>]*>)` is a negative lookahead ([ref](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)).  It scans forward from the current position (in this case, after a quote has been matched) looking for a closing angle bracket (`>`).  If it finds one without seeing an opening bracket (`<`) first, it must be inside an HTML tag, so the match fails.

```js
var str = 'Foobar is so "awesome."  I <span prop="nifty">"really"</span> <span prop="attr">think it is so</span> <span prop="nifty" prop="attr">"cool!"</span>';
str = str.replace(/"(?![^<>]*>)/g, "&#34;");
alert(str);
```

As the other responders said, it's best to process HTML *as* HTML whenever possible (and it usually is possible).  Processing it character-by-character like this, it's much too easy to introduce errors, even if you're an expert with whatever tool you're using.

Answer (score 5):

As always, it is a very bad idea to do HTML/XML processing using regular expressions.

Anyway, I guess one can use the following regular expression:

```
([^<]*<[^>]*>[^<]*)*?\"(.*?)\"
```

The first group is used to ensure that every opened tag, is closed as well. The second group ensures you match anything between the quotes.

---

If you however, want to do it properly, you can use `tidy` to convert it to an xml file and then use for instance `xmlint` to perform *XPath* queries. I'm sure Javascript has such tools as well.

**Example** (in `bash`):

```
$ echo 'Foobar is so "awesome."  I <span prop="nifty">"really"</span> <span prop="attr">think it is so</span> <span prop="nifty" prop="attr">"cool!"</span>' | tidy -asxhtml -numeric 2>/dev/null | xmllint --html --xpath 'normalize-space(/)' - | grep -P -o '".*?"'
"awesome."
"really"
"cool!"
```

Comment: What do you suggest for such parsing if not regex? Also, SublimeText is selecting the entire sentence up to the last `"` for me

Comment: @philtune i would suggest grabbing all of the text nodes and manipulating them directly (if and only if it couldn't be done server-side.)

Comment: Most of the time I use `tidy` to convert the file to XML and then use `xmllint` or another `xpath` program to process it.

Comment: Thanks for the tools, but I meant how would you code for it?

Comment: @philtune: in JS or using the tools, updated answer with usage for `tidy` and `xmllint`...

Comment: Hahaha, after reading http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/938516, I rest my curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is use a DOM parser to read the whole document, and then output the whole document as valid HTML.  Then you don't even have to mess with it, and you'll be getting the best possible interpretation of your invalid ambiguous HTML.

- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6427641/362536

Answer (score 0):

For problems like this, I find it easier to process individual text nodes rather than struggle through regex syntax.

Assuming your string is *not* within a DOM element, you can easily create an element, and simply not attach it to the DOM.

My function below iterates through the child nodes.  If the child is a text node, it changes `"` to `&#34;`.  Otherwise, it calls itself recursively with the child.  The output is then stored in a `textarea`:

```js
function replaceQuotes(d) {
  var cn= d.childNodes;
  for(var i = 0 ; i < cn.length ; i++) {
    if(cn[i].nodeValue) {
      cn[i].nodeValue= cn[i].nodeValue.replace(/"/g,'&#34;');
    }
    else {
      replaceQuotes(cn[i]);
    }
  }
}

var str = 'Foobar is so "awesome."  I <span prop="nifty">"really"</span> <span prop="attr">think it is so</span> <span prop="nifty" prop="attr">"cool!"</span>'

var d= document.createElement('div');
d.innerHTML= str;
replaceQuotes(d);

document.querySelector('textarea').innerHTML= d.innerHTML;
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```